# How to display the indices/element positions of a ragged array?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a three-level ragged array like so:

```
array = {{{a, a, a, a}, {a, a, a, a}, {a, a, a}}, {{a}, {a, a, a, 
     a}, {a, a, a, a}}, {{a, a}, {a, a, a}, {a, a, a, a}, {a, a, a, 
     a}}, {{a, a, a, a}, {a, a, a, a}, {a, a}, {a, a, a}}, {{a, a, 
     a}, {a, a, a, a}, {a, a, a}, {a, a, a, a}}};
Grid[array, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want to display the indices of this array by replacing each `a` element by the 3-digit positions of that element. I also want to preserve the structure of the array i.e. no flattening of the original array should occur. Below is an excerpt of what I want my result to be; notice that each number matches up with the position of the `a` that was previously in that position, and all the the curly brackets are preserved.

```
{{{111, 112, 113, 114}, {121, 122, 123, 124}, {131, 132, 133}}, ...}
```

I tried to use `Position[array, a]` but I only got back a flattened list of all the positions of `a`, which makes sense since `Position` is only supposed to show me the positions of `a` without preserving the list hierarchy.

```
Position[array, a]
(* {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 4}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1,
   2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 3}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 
  2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 4}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 3,
   3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 
  3}, {3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 
  2}, {3, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 4}, {4, 1, 1}, {4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 3}, {4, 1, 
  4}, {4, 2, 1}, {4, 2, 2}, {4, 2, 3}, {4, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 1}, {4, 3, 
  2}, {4, 4, 1}, {4, 4, 2}, {4, 4, 3}, {5, 1, 1}, {5, 1, 2}, {5, 1, 
  3}, {5, 2, 1}, {5, 2, 2}, {5, 2, 3}, {5, 2, 4}, {5, 3, 1}, {5, 3, 
  2}, {5, 3, 3}, {5, 4, 1}, {5, 4, 2}, {5, 4, 3}, {5, 4, 4}} *)
```

---

**My question is:**

How do I display the indices of a (ragged) array elements--preferably concatenated instead of `{_,_,_}`--*and* still keep the list structures intact?

---

**PS**: Here are some other things that I've tried which did not work:

1) `array /. a -> Position[array, a]`

This did not work because each `a` is replaced by a huge list of *all* positions of a in the array.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

2) `array /. array[[i_, j_, k_]] -> 100 i + 10 j + k`

This would not work either because apparently `Part` does not take patterns.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
MapIndexed[StringJoin[ToString /@ #2] &, array, {-1}]
```

Comment: lol that's the quickest I've ever deleted an answer :)

Comment: hm yes, I saw "there's 1 new answer", clicked on it and saw your deleted answer!

Comment: omg you rock! I want to kiss you right now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ReplacePart[]` :

```
ReplacePart[array, x : {_, _, _} :> StringJoin[ToString /@  x]]
```

Comment: I really wish I could also accept this answer as this is such an intuitive yet elegant approach.

Answer (score 2):

This may also help

```
array2 = array;(*To preserve the original matrix*)
p = Position[array2, a];
(array2[[Sequence @@ #]] = StringJoin[ToString /@ #]) & /@ p;
array2
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Algohi. I was first intrigued by your having pure functions on both sides of the equations but after seeing the full form of your method (`(array2[[Sequence @@ #]] = StringJoin[ToString /@ #]) & /@ p // Hold // FullForm`), it became clear set the `=` is a mere `Set` function that could be mapped to all `p`. Now I understand why in MMA, "everything is an expression".

Comment: @seismatica yes you are correct. everything in MMA is an expression. thank you for your comment:)